# django middleware redirect doesn't render page

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, django-middleware

I am writing custom middlware that I want to redirect to another page if a condition is met.  My code looks like this:

```
class SettingHandler(object):  

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs): 
        if request.user.paid: 
            return view_func(request, *view_args, **view_kwargs)

        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('setting'))
```

My urls.py looks like this:

```
url(r'^setting/$', 'customers.settings', name='setting'),
```

When the redirect condition is reached, the page doesn't render.  The output in the console looks like this:

```
"GET /setting/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
"GET /setting/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
"GET /setting/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
"GET /setting/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
"GET /setting/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
"GET /setting/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
"GET /setting/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
"GET /setting/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
"GET /setting/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
```

How can I redirect to the desired page?

Comment: Could you show your `urls.py`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual error from the browser was "redirect loop".

I put an exclusion case to get it out of the loop and all worked fine

Comment: I am facing this same problem. Can you please give some example to put an exclusion case.

Answer (score 0):

This will fix your immediate issue:

```
if request.setting or request.path == '/setting/':
```

But it's pretty hacky. There's probably a better way, but it'll depend on what you are trying to accomplish - IOW, what is the condition you're testing?

Comment: the request attribute is actually based around a user and a paid flag.  I think accidentally naming it setting changed things a bit.